# Add RCTCameraRoll using only Cocoapods

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

I was expecting that with only this:

```
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
  'Core',
  'CxxBridge',
  'DevSupport',
  'RCTText',
  'RCTNetwork',
  'RCTWebSocket',
  'RCTAnimation',
  'RCTCameraRoll'
]
```

I could start using the `CameraRoll` API. But it doesn't look enough.
Because limitations in our project architecture I cannot manually link any binary.

Is there a way to use the `CameraRoll`? As far as I understand other APIs like `Animation` are automatically included by react-native so have to be a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
pod 'React-RCTCameraRoll', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CameraRoll'
```

to your Podfile (RN >= 0.60)

Comment: It appears the podspec file is missing on 0.61.2 for CameraRoll